# What should be "AssignUserId" if I use proftpd mysql mod

Tags: mysql, apache, ftp, proftpd

I have several websites on the same VPC. I set up ftp with a help of proftpd with mysql mod and made 3 users. The ftp works fine.

I need Apache to work with files on ftp not changing owner, so i installed apache2-mpm-itk. Now in every site config file i need to add "AssignUserId" parameter.

User id and group id of files on ftp 5500.

For example if i had real user "user1", i would type "AssignUserId www-data user1"
But in my case i don't know what this parameter should be.

Comment: I find the answer here http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/

Comment: AssignUserID: "Takes two parameters, uid and gid (or really, user name and group name; use “#<uid>” if you want to specify a raw uid)". So in my case it is: "AssignUserId #5500 #5500"